# How to send logs to GCP using StructuredLogHandler with jsonPayload?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, logging

I am trying to send logs (with jsonPayload) to GCP using StructuredLogHandler with below python code.

```
rootlogger = logging.getLogger()

client = google.cloud.logging.Client(credentials=xxx, project=xxx)

h = StructuredLogHandler()
    
rootlogger.addHandler(h)

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.warning('warning')
```

I see that logs are being printed on console (in json format) but the logs are not sent to GCP Log Explorer. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v3 of Python Cloud Logging Library it's now easier than ever as it integrates with the Python standard logging library with `client.setup_logging`:

```py
import logging
import google.cloud.logging

# Instantiate a client
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()

# Retrieves a Cloud Logging handler based on the environment
# you're running in and integrates the handler with the
# Python logging module. By default this captures all logs
# at INFO level and higher
client.setup_logging()
```

Name your logger as usual. E.g.

```
logger = logging.getLogger('test')
```

Then if you want to send structured log messages to Cloud Logging then you can use one of two methods:

1. Use the `json_fields` `extra` argument:

```
data_dict = {"hello": "world"}
logging.info("message field", extra={"json_fields": data_dict})
```

2. Use a JSON-parseable string (requires importing the `json` module):

```
import json

data_dict = {"hello": "world"}
logging.info(json.dumps(data_dict))
```

This will see your log messages sent to Google Cloud and the JSON payload available under the `jsonPayload` field of the expanded log entry:

[image]

Comment: this works great! thank you! few followup questions - as you mentioned, `client.setup_logging` retrieves a Cloud Logging handler based on the environment, my question is: on what basis does it pick the environment? Is there a difference if I set the CloudLoggingHandler manually? I also want to include few attributes from LogRecord (like lineno, funcName etc) as part of the message, how to do that? using setFormatter?

Comment: It picks the correct handlers based on where it's being run so it handles the differences between different compute platforms accordingly. It also detects if JSON is included and then appropriate selects Python's `StructuredLogHandler` accordingly, etc. [Formatters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) work just as with standard Python logging

Comment: that helps! my last question (in my previous comment) was: how to include LogRecord attributes (like lineno, funcName) as part of jsonpayload?

Comment: You don't need to. Those are all included as part of the logging information (see here: https://d.pr/i/4xAPKQ).

Comment: interesting! there are few other attributes in LogRecord like processName, threadName, exc_info etc.. it doesn't exists as part of logging information.. is there a way to include them as well?

Comment: Write that up as a separate question as it's moved away from your original one and starts getting nested in comments.

Comment: sure, posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74902031/how-to-include-logrecord-attributes-as-part-of-logging-information-on-gcp-in-js)