# How to include LogRecord attributes as part of logging information on GCP (in json format)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, logging

I would like to send LogRecord attributes (like processName, threadName, exc_info etc) as part of logging information on GCP in json format. How to do that? I am using below python code to send logs to GCP (with jsonpayload)

(thanks @[ianyoung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127427/ianyoung) [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74895143/how-to-send-logs-to-gcp-using-structuredloghandler-with-jsonpayload))

```
import logging
import google.cloud.logging
import json

client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.setup_logging()

logger = logging.getLogger('test')

data_dict = {"hello": "world"}
logging.info(json.dumps(data_dict))
```

Comment: This would require a complete modification of the parser which is responsible reading and writing the logs to Cloud Logging from Dataflow workers. To explain this further, you cannot piggyback the default Dataflow work logging system. The default worker logging system works in 2 phases. 1) Java SDK process writing logs into local files.
2) The logging agent process parses the local files and bulk-sends logs into Cloud Logging.

Comment: The logging agent process at (2) only handles a fixed set of fields, so it cannot handle extra fields like "jsonPayload.codeUrl". That is what the sentence - "cannot be re-used", "parser only respects a fixed set of fields" - emphasises on.

Comment: In summary, you can make the fully customised work log format, but it means you should reimplement what the default worker logging system is doing. It's "possible", but definitely not easy. Some bad implementations can cause Cloud Logging quota issues or some logs lost. Please do understand such logging changes need to be tested end to end and can lead to logs being lost as mentioned, which can make it extremely difficult for GCP Support to troubleshoot your Dataflow jobs going forward.